# sql order query by orderno asc, same customer after orderdate

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I am using this query:

```
SELECT  c.Name
    ,   o.custid
    ,   o.orderno
    ,   o.orderdate
FROM orders o
INNER JOIN customers c ON o.custid = c.custid
ORDER BY Name, orderno, departmentid ASC, orderdate ASC
```

I want to obtain for the same `custid`, the `orderdate asc`.  The condition 
`order by name, orderno ,departmentid asc` is mandatory.

Example: .....

```
    James 1 10101 110332 28081312 - time
    James 1 10101 110332 29081312  
    ....
```

Comment: Can you provide example input data and expected output?

Comment: It seems you already get the orderdate with your query;so what's precisely the problem ?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  c.Name
    ,   o.custid
    ,   o.orderno
    ,   o.orderdate
FROM orders o
INNER JOIN customers c ON o.custid = c.custid
ORDER BY custid, orderdate
```

BY Default it's ASC if  you want to Desending then write DESC end of query.

Comment: Adding orderdate asc, destroys the previous order, comparing with other customers. That way i said "Name, orderno, departmentid" should be mainted for all customers, but when the customer is the same, the orders should be only order by orderdate. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use Group-by clause at the end of your query.

`GROUP BY o.custid`